# How to return an object in Redux?

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-thunk

I have a button that, when clicked, sends an object [ Dispatch(ADDS(myObject) ], but my [ Reducer ] does not return the object as the first ( index 0 ), it returns the first item ( empty ) because the ( InitialState ) it is set to ( empty ). How do I return the object as ( Index 0 ) ?

**Console.log**

[console.log - Prinscreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JO3c8.png)

**My UI.js**

```
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

export const slice = createSlice({
    name: 'initial',
    
    initialState : {
        product: [],
    },
    
    reducers: {
        ADDS(state, actions) {
            return {
                ...state, 
                product: actions.payload,
            } 
        }
    }
});

export const { ADDS } = slice.actions;

export default slice.reducer;
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

here destructure your reducer response like this `product: [...state.product, actions.payload]`

```
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

export const slice = createSlice({
    name: 'initial',
    
    initialState : {
        product: [],
    },
    
    reducers: {
        ADDS(state, actions) {
            return{
              ...state,
              product: [...state.product, actions.payload]
            }
        }
    }
});

export const { ADDS } = slice.actions;

export default slice.reducer;
```

Comment: Now it is joining the value ( empty ) to the ( new data ), so the return in console.log is the same as the image attached to my doubt.

Answer (score 0):

You are currently replacing your array with your object in the reducer.

It’s not quite clear what you’re trying to achieve here, do you just want to add every new dispatched object to the array?

If so you need to something like this

```
product: state.push(actions.payload),
```

Comment: Yes, I need add the ( actions.payload ) return, to ( state.product ) array.